# Lock Android Phone/Tablet after a certain time

Tags: parental-control

I have my younger brother who spends too much time playing on Android Tablet, he wastes too much time and I've decided to give him only 1 hour a day but he's clever and uses the time in two shifts (30 minutes each), but I can actually tell him to use it once. Anyways, I want an app which will lock the phone after it's used for 30 minutes or 60 minutes automatically or shut down, whichever is possible.

He also uses extra time without me knowing (I can't always keep watching at him), so I want to eliminate everything and get some discipline to him.

It would be good if its linked with some website to track it but if not its fine, what I'm looking is an Android version of CyberCafePro (if possible) or anything that will auto lock the Android device after a certain amount of time and can be unlocked with a password or some sort of combination.

Comment: Far as I know locking the screen is not a privilege that a user app can have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the excellent app "[Kids Place](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiddoware.kidsplace)" which acts as a launcher for kids. With this, you can choose what apps they are allowed to start, and how long they are allowed to use the tablet each day.

> An app launcher with parental controls & child lock that protects your personal data and restricts kids to apps you have approved. Kids Place also prevents children from downloading new apps, making phone calls, texting or performing other actions that can cost you money. Includes convenience features for parents such as auto app restart, useful for small kids who accidentally exit launched apps. With Kids Place app, kids gets fun time and parents can get some much needed peace and free time.
>   Trusted by millions of families.No internet connection; no email; no account creation and no payment required for app to work.
>
> Features:
>   ★ Custom home screen displays only apps that parents have authorized
>   ★ Can prevent children from buying or downloading new apps
>   ★ Timer feature to lock Kids Place after specified amount of time. 
>   ★ Support Multiple User Profiles. 
>   ★ Capable of blocking incoming calls when Kids Place is running
>   ★ Capable of disabling all wireless signals while Kids Place is running
>   ★ Can restarts apps accidentally stopped by small children, allowing parents to stay focused on their own tasks.
>   ★ Add custom wallpaper to customize your child’s experience while in Kids Place
>   ★ Appropriate for children of all ages - babies, toddlers, even teenagers
>   ★ Plugins - Kids Place provides additional parental controls for Website content filtering; Videos and Pictures via plugin based design. Please go to setting > plugins to access these features.
>
> Premium Features (requires In-App purchase)
>   ★ Run in background mode. Kids Place will not be used as a launcher or home screen. Suitable for older kids or on 
>   employees device to be used with stock launcher.
>   ★ Added option to always start on reboot.
>   ★ Ability to block app uninstall. 
>   ★ Customize App Title
>
> Home; Back; Search and Call buttons are locked so that kid cannot get out of the Kids Place or make phone calls.